# Which is correct? "You are exception/exceptional."

Tags: word-choice

Me and my friend were wondering weather which sentence is right:

- You are exception
- You are exceptional

The meaning we are trying to portray is you are different.. so based in this meaning which sentence is right?

Answer (score 3):

Your question has several errors.

**Me and my friend were wondering...** is incorrect. **Me** is the object form in English. You need the subject form: **My friend and I were wondering....**.

The test is to ask yourself, can I say: **Me was wondering....** If the answer is no, you also can't say **Me and my friend were wondering...**

Furthermore, **weather** refers to the rain, sun, wind etc that is being experienced. The spelling you require is **whether**, although the pronunciation is the same.

Coming to your question, the word **exception** is a noun. The word **exceptional** is an adjective. We use adjectives, not nouns, to modify other nouns or pronouns, such as **you**.

Thus, you would say to someone: **You are an exceptional person** or just **you are exceptional**, signifying outstanding  or excellent rather than just unusual.

On the other hand, you might say: **You are an exception....**, which really just means that you are different in some respect from most people.